# Configuring custom Kafka Consumer Deserializer in application.properties file. [spring boot]

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want to consume avro messages and deserialize them without using the Confluent schema registry. I have the schema locally. So, for that, I followed this https://medium.com/@mailshine/apache-avro-quick-example-in-kafka-7b2909396c02 for Consumer part only. Now, I want to configure this deserializer in the application.properties file (the Spring boot way).
I tried adding
`spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=com.example.AvroDeserializer`
But this results in error saying "Could not find a public no-argument constructor for com.example.AvroDeserializer".
Is there any way to call the constructor with argument from application.properties configuration.
Or
Do I need to configure this in Code instead of properties?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using properties, but you have to do it via the `configure` method (with a no-arg constructor) - this is because Kafka instantiates the deserializer, not Spring.

See the `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer` source code for an example.

Otherwise, you can just inject your Deserializer into the consumer factory...

```java
@Bean
MyDeserializer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Foo> factory) {
    MyDeserializer<Foo> deser = new MyDeserializer<>(...);
    factory.setValueDeserializer(deser);
    return deser;
}
```